# Big Oh of interesting nested loop - how to count it?

Tags: loops, big-o, nested-loops

I know there is many similar questions about the Big Oh notation, but this example is quite interesting and not trivial:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

The outer loop will iterate lg(N) times, but what with inner loop? And what is T(N) for all the operations? 
I can see only 3 posibilities :

- T(N) = lg(N) * 2^N
- T(N) = log(N) * (N-1)
- T(N) = N

My opinion - T(N) = N    - but it is just my intuition from observations value of sum variable when N was multiplied many times - sum was almost equal to 2N, which gives us N.

Basically I do not know how to count it. Please help me with this task and explain the solution - it is quite important for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop iterates the last time max. N. Before the last run it iterates N/2. If you sum it up N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 This add up to 2*N. And that's all as you counted all runs. T(N) = N

Comment: Great, so this is what I have expected. But why this special time we should not count it as outer loop * inner loop ?

Comment: Actually we count the outer loop. That's why we add up the different runtimes.

Comment: Shouldn't be counted as 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + ... + N ??? At first i=1, later 2, 4, 8 ...

T(N) = 2^N ?? It looks like i should use the sum of geometric series: **[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)**

Comment: SORRY! My mistake! N is not the number of the elements that should be summed. It is the last number - and this add up to ~2N. You were right from the beginning!